# Why does this not seem to be random?

Tags: python, math, random, statistics, average

I was running a procedure to be like one of those games were people try to guess a number between 0 and 100 where there are 100 people guessing.I then averaged how many different guesses there are.

```
import random
def averager(times):
    tests=[]
    for i in range(times):
        l=[]
        for i in range(0,100):
            l.append(random.randint(0,100))
        tests.append(len(set(l)))
    return (sum(tests))/len(tests)

print(averager(1000))
```

For some reason, the number of different guesses averages out to 63.6

Why is this?Is it due to a flaw in the python random library?

In a scenario where people were guessing a number between 1 and 10

The first person has a 100% chance to guess a previously unguessed number

The second person has a 90% chance to guess a previously unguessed number

The third person has a 80% chance to guess a previously unguessed number

and so on...

The average chance of guessing a new number(by my reasoning) is 55%.
 But the data doesn't reflect this.

Comment: I'm assuming you would expect it to be closer to 50?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `set(l)`?  It is possible for different people to guess the *same* number.

Comment: No, it's a flaw in your reasoning. What do you expect the result to be, and why?

Comment: Think through a simpler case.  Say there are only two people, and each can guess either 0 or 1, so the guess list will be either [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], or [1,1].  What will the expected number of different guesses be?

Comment: You need to read up on the [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox).

Comment: I think you can nearly always assume that if you've found a bug/flaw in some programming language's standard library or implementation that you are probably misunderstanding some detail of how it will work.

Comment: Here is the math Stack Exchange page for anyone interested - http://math.stackexchange.com/q/637664/121151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is for finding the average *number of unique guesses* made by 100 people each guessing a number from 1 to 100. 
As for why it converges to a number around 63... you should post your question to the math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a completely flat distribution, you would expect the average to come out as 100, meaning everybody's guess was different.  However, you know that such a scenario is much less random than a scenario where you have duplication.  The fact that you get repeated numbers during a random sequence should be comforting.

All you are doing here is measuring some kind of uniqueness within very small sets: *ie* 1000 repeats of an experiment involving 100 random values.  You might get a better appreciation of this if you use some sort of bootstrapping algorithm to sample from.

Also, if you scale up the number of repeats to millions, and perhaps measure the sample distribution (not just the mean), you'll have a little more confidence in the results you're getting.

It may be that the pseudo-random generator has a characteristic which yields approximately 60-70% non-repeated values inside a sequence the same length as the range.  However, you would need to experiment with far more samples, as well as different random seeds.  Otherwise your results are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so it would take an already generated sequence as input, rather than calculating random numbers:

```
def averager(seqs):
    tests = []
    for s in seqs:
        tests.append(len(set(s)))
    return float(sum(tests))/len(tests)
```

Then I made a function to return *all* possible choices for any given number of people and guess range:

```
def combos(n, limit):
    return itertools.product(*((range(limit),) * n))
```

(One of the things I *love* about Python is that it's so easy to break apart a function into trivial pieces.)

Then I started testing with increasing numbers:

```
for n in range(2,100):
    x = averager(combos(n, n))
    print n, x, x/n

2 1.5 0.75
3 2.11111111111 0.703703703704
4 2.734375 0.68359375
5 3.3616 0.67232
6 3.99061213992 0.66510202332
7 4.62058326038 0.660083322911
8 5.25112867355 0.656391084194
```

This algorithm has a *horrible* complexity, so at this point I got a MemoryError. As you can see, the percentage of unique results keeps dropping as the number of people and guess range keeps increasing.

Repeating the test with random numbers:

```
def rands(repeats, n, limit):
    for i in range(repeats):
        yield [random.randint(0, limit) for j in range(n)]

for n in range(10, 101, 10):
    x = averager(rands(10000, n, n))
    print n, x, x/n

10 6.7752 0.67752
20 13.0751 0.653755
30 19.4131 0.647103333333
40 25.7309 0.6432725
50 32.0471 0.640942
60 38.3333 0.638888333333
70 44.6882 0.638402857143
80 50.948 0.63685
90 57.3525 0.63725
100 63.6322 0.636322
```

As you can see the results are consistent with what we saw earlier and with your own observation. I'm sure a bit of combinatorial math could explain it all.